# How to retrieve data using json parsing when there are multiple inner nodes?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am trying to retrieve data using a `URL` using  `Json Parsing` in  Android.

I have done the following coding but I am not able to figure out how to parse the node which is present in the inner node `items`.

My json array and codes are posted as below. Please guide me step by step.

Part of the Json Array

```
[
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "11",
            "Item_Id": "123",
            "Item_Name": "Chicken Cream Soup",
            "Price": "8",
            "Currency": "AED",
            "Category": "Soup",
            "Description": "Creamy Chicken Soup with garnish & side helpings",
            "Unit": "2",
            "food_type": "Non",
            "Image_Large": "/images_large/chickensoup.jpg",
            "Image_Thumb": "/images_large/chickensoup.jpg",
            "Timestamp": "6/23/2014 9:49:43 PM",
            "Promotion": "",
            "Item_Name_arabic": "حساء الطماطم",
            "Item_Name_russian": "",
            "Currency_arabic": "درهم",
            "Currency_russian": "",
            "Description_arabic": "حساء الطماطم",
            "Description_russian": "",
            "Note": "",
            "Nutritional_info": "",
            "extrafield_1": "",
            "extrafield_2": "",
            "preferncess": [
                "No Salt",
                "Extra Sugar"
            ],
            "preferncess_ids": [
                "1",
                "2"
            ],
            "price": [
                "4",
                "5"
            ],
            "preferncess_arabic": [
                "لا الملح",
                "سكر اضافية"
            ]
        },
```

MainActivity.class

```
 try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                items = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);
                Log.i("json node",""+items);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = items.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    //String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    Log.w("myid", id);
                                           } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Do you want to parse `preferncess` node ??

Comment: I want to parse all the nodes present in the url i.e items and preferences

Comment: you will need nested parsing...

Comment: check my answer and let me know if you have any problem with it...

Answer (score 0):

```
 // fetch item array
 JSONArray  itemObjectArray = jsonStr.getJSONArray("items"); 
 for (int i = 0; i < itemObjectArray.length(); i++) {

        // fetch item object at i position
         JSONObject  itemObject = itemObjectArray.getJSONObject(i); 

        // fetch values  from itemObject 
        String idValue = itemObject.getString("id");
        String noteValue = itemObject.getString("Note");

        // fetch the array 
        JSONArrayprefObject = itemObject.getJSONArray("preferncess");

        // iterate throgh the array like
        for (int i = 0; i < prefObject .length(); i++) {
                  JSONObject p = prefObject .getJSONObject(i);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

preference is json array you can retrive it by `c.getJSONArray("preferncess"); and then iterating.` or in more generic you can Can you try something like following

```
 if (c.get(key) instanceof String)
                     {
                        JSONObject Lawset = c.getString(key);                        
                     } else if (c.get(key) instanceof JSONObject)
                     {
                        JSONObject Lawset = c.getJSONObject(key);                        

                        //try to retrieve data from json object
                     }
                     else if (c.get(key) instanceof JSONArray)
                    {
                        JSONArray Lawset = c.getJSONArray(key);
                                    //iterate to get data
                    }
```